# Clear out unconverted leads in qualified status

Tags: community, leads, professional-edition

**I am using Professional Edition.**

I want  to clear out unconverted `Lead` records with a `Status` of "qualified".

We have `Lead` records that are not converted but their status is qualified, which is incorrect

How can I make it so there are no longer unconverted `Lead` records with qualified `Status`?

Comment: Is this a once off data cleanup, or is it more about ensuring an unconverted lead cannot have a status of 'qualified'?

Comment: @ Nick Cook
I need the leads with status = “qualified” to change to something else - anything but qualified.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an Appexchange package such as [Mass Edit + Mass Update + Mass Delete](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003J6KcEAK) that is a) free and b) works with PE

or, [Excel Connector](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gtRnAAI) is suggested as also workable for PE

Answer (score -1):

create the batch to get the unconverted leads and update the status of those leads. Schedule that batch to run daily or your convinced time

Comment: i am using  professional edition and its  not possible to use the apex in this edition.

Any other help would be appreciated .